# Regular expressions - capturing groups confusion

Tags: java, regex

I am reading an Oracle tutorial on regular expressions. I am on the topic *[Capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)*. Though the reference is excellent, but except that a parenthesis represents a group, I am finding many difficulties in understanding the topic. Here are my confusions.

1. What is the significance of counting groups in an expression?
2. What are non-capturing groups?

Elaborating with examples would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a string, `abcabc`, and you want to figure out whether the first part of the string matches the second part. You can do this with a single regex by using capturing groups and backreferences. Here is the regex I would use:

```
(.+)\1
```

The way this works is `.+` matches any sequence of characters. Because it is in parentheses, it is *caught* in a group. `\1` is a *backreference* to the `1`st capturing group, so it is the equivalent of the text caught by the capturing group. After a bit of backtracking, the capturing group matches the first part of the string, `abc`. The backreference `\1` is now the equivalent of `abc`, so it matches the second half of the string. The entire string is now matched, so it is confirmed that the first half of the string matches the second half.

---

Another use of backreferences is in replacing. Say you want to replace all `{...}` with `[...]`, if the text inside `{` and `}` is only digits. You can easily do this with capturing groups and backreferences, using the regex

```
{(\d+)}
```

And replacing with that with `[\1]`.

The regex matches `{123}` in the string `abc {123} 456`, and captures `123` in the first capturing group. The backreference `\1` is now the equivalent of `123`, so replacing `{(\d+)}` in `abc {123} 456` with `[\1]` results in `abc [123] 456`.

---

The reason non-capturing groups exist is because groups in general have more uses that just capturing. The regex `(xyz)+` matches a string that consists entirely of the group, `xyz`, repeated, such as `xyzxyzxyz`. A group is needed because `xyz+` only matches `xy` and then `z` repeated, i.e. `xyzzzzz`. The problem with using capturing groups is that they are slightly less efficient compared to non-capturing groups, and they take up an index. If you have a complicated regex with a lot of groups in it, but you only need to reference a single one somewhere in the middle, it's a lot better to just reference `\1` rather than trying to count all the groups up to the one you want.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Ryan. The examples were very helpful. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

1. One usually doesn't *count* groups other than to know which group has which number. E.g. `([abc])([def](\d+))` has three groups, so I know to refer to them as `\1`, `\2` and `\3`. Note that group 3 is *inside* 2. They are numbered from the left by where they *begin*.
2. When *searching* with regex to find something in a string, as opposed to *matching* when you make sure the whole string matches the subject, group 0 will give you just the matched string, but not the stuff that was before or after it. Imagine if you will a pair of brackets around your whole regex. It's not part of the total count because it's not really considered a group.
3. Groups can be used for other things than capturing. E.g. `(foo|bar)` will match `"foo"` *or* `"bar"`. If you're not interested in the contents of a group, you can make it non-capturing (e.g: `(?:foo|bar)` (varies by dialect)), so as not to "use up" the numbers assigned to groups. But you don't *have to*, it's just convenient sometimes.
4. Say I want to find a word that begins and ends in the same letter: `\b([a-z])[a-z]*\1\b` The `\1` will then be the same as whatever the first group captured. Of course it can be used for much more powerful stuff, but I think you'll get the idea.

(Coming up with relevant examples is certainly the hardest part.)

Edit: I answered when the questions were:

> 1. What is the significance of counting groups in an expression?
> 2. There is a special group, called as group-0, which means the entire expression. It is not  reported by groupCount() method. Why is that?
> 3. I don't understand what are non-capturing groups?
> 4. Why we need back-references? What is the significance of back-references?

Comment: @benz Say I have a regex with a number of groups whose contents I want to use. I make them capturing groups so that I can use their contents (in the regex itself with backreferences (`\1`, etc.), or in whatever regex lib I'm using (e.g `match.GetGroup(1)`)). Then suppose I have a place where I want to match one of three words, but I don't care which one it is: `...(?:one|two|three)...` I make it non-capturing, so as not to assign it a number; only the groups in whose contents I'm interested will have numbers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can't think of an appropriate example at the moment, but I'm assuming someone might need to know the number of sub matches in the RegEx.
2. Group 0 is always the entire base match. I'm assuming `groupCount()` just lets you know how many capture groups you've specified in the expression.
3. A non-capturing group `(?:)` would be used to, well, not capture a group. Ex. if you need to test if a string contains one of several words and don't want to capture the word in a new group: `(?:hello|hi there) world` !== `hello|hi there world`. The first matches "hello world" or "hi there world" but the second matches "hello" or "hi there world".
4. They can be used as a part of a multitude of powerful reasons, such as testing whether or not a number is prime or composite. :) Or you could simply test to ensure a search parameter isn't repeated, ie. `^(\d)(?!.*\1)\d+$` would ensure the first digit is unique in a string.

Comment: While [interesting](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20338/match-strings-whose-length-is-isolated-prime), testing prime numbers should be done with integer operation, not regex. It is more of a possibility, rather than a good solution.